# Key Error despite code previously working

Tags: python, keyerror

```
predictors = ['gender','SeniorCitizen','Partner', 'Dependents','tenure','PhoneService',\
         'MultipleLines','InternetService','OnlineSecurity','OnlineBackup','DeviceProtection',\
         'TechSupport','StreamingTV','StreamingMovies','Contract','PaperlessBilling',\
         'PaymentMethod','MonthlyCharges','TotalCharges']
```

This line of code is from a project I have to do for a school assignment to create a decision tree. I copied and pasted the line from a different project, changing only the variable names, so it should have worked. I've already double checked the variable names in the code against the data file I'm using. But for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
KeyError: "['gender' 'Partner' 'Dependents' 'PhoneService' 'MultipleLines'\n 'InternetService' 'OnlineSecurity' 'OnlineBackup' 'DeviceProtection'\n 'TechSupport' 'StreamingTV' 'StreamingMovies' 'Contract'\n 'PaperlessBilling' 'PaymentMethod'] not in index"
```

I know the data is in the .csv file that I'm using, and I know it worked earlier in the same code in the k-nearest-neighbor method.

EDIT: Here is the line Python doesn't like:

```
dt.fit(training[predictors],training['Churn'])
```

And here is the definition of dt:

```
dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
```

EDIT 2: Here is a list of all the dummy variables in this list

```
data = pandas.get_dummies(data, columns=['gender','SeniorCitizen','Partner','Dependents','PhoneService','MultipleLines', 'InternetService', \
   'OnlineSecurity','OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV', \
   'StreamingMovies', 'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod'])
```

Comment: no error here for the assignment to predictors. share more or even the whole program?

Comment: Sure. What do you need to know?

Comment: Since predictors is a list of string and 'Churn' is a string, I think the problem might arise because you are using both to index the training (I guess it can only be indexed by string).

Comment: Predictors is a list of some dummies, some floats, and some strings. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to put comma after every variable of your predictors.
See the error, it says

```
KeyError: "['gender' 'Partner' 'Dependents' 'PhoneService' 'MultipleLines'\n 'InternetService' 'OnlineSecurity' 'OnlineBackup' 'DeviceProtection'\n 'TechSupport' 'StreamingTV' 'StreamingMovies' 'Contract'\n 'PaperlessBilling' 'PaymentMethod'] not in index"
```

You said that you copied the line from different source, maybe they don't have comma between variables (Not sure).
So here, you have no comma after 'gender'(, -> you should put comma) 'Partner'(,-> you should put comma) ... . So you are getting error because program assume all the variables as one variable.

Try to edit and may it work.